# get редирект .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день. Помогите сделать редирект на `.html` файлы.

Как сделать что бы если мы введем `mysite/product.php?id_product=N` сработал редирект на `mysite/N-product-name.html`, где `N` — это ID товара; при этом дальнейшее название товара меняется? Пример: `mysite/N-platbe-zelenoe.html`, `mysite/N-tovar-krossovki.html`.

Сейчас работает так: если вводим `mysite/product.php?id_product=N`, то перенаправляется на `mysite/my-product-name.html`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_product=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://mysite/10005966-product-name.html? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Средствами **.htaccess** это можно сделать только вручную, прописав соответствия редиректа по всем соответствующим страницам сайта.

Это связано с тем, что используемая CMS формирует ссылки вида `mysite/product.php?id_product=N`, где идентификатор определяется через `id_product`.

Чтобы решить вашу проблему, CMS должна отдавать ссылки вида `mysite/N-product_slug`, где идентификатором будет `product_slug` (если он, конечно, формируется CMS). Отмечу, что `N` в этом случае чаще всего лишнее. (Чтобы избежать одинаковых адресов при одинаковых `slugs`, многие CMS добавляют уникальную цифру к адресу - например, так делает Joomla).